# Interface not drawn if becomeCurrentPage is called by a late page

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfacecontroller

Just like Sarah said in this link:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26922
I have the same problem by using the method "becomeCurrentPage" when I called "presentControllerWithNames()" and the pages is more than 5.
I have a WatchKit app where the initial controller creates a 15 page interface called using presentControllerWithNames().
All of these are the same sub-classed WKInterfaceController.
Depending on the context data passed, one of the first 15 pages will call becomeCurrentPage() during awakeWithContext() to make it the active page.
This works fine so long as it is one of the early pages but for later pages, the display appears blank.
If I swipe back through the pages, nothing appears until I get to page 4 which displays after a slight pause. After that swiping forwards or backwards shows the expected displays. 
With the debugger I can see that the interface elements have all been initialised and can be accessed programmatically. They are not set to hidden, but they do not appear.

Writing a very simple test app, I have found that the problem was not the total number of pages but the index of the page that calls becomeCurrentPage().
And this is not consistent between simulator and watch or from test to test.

In my test app, running on the simulator, an app with 30 pages will always work if any page up to and including 18 is made active.
Activating page 19 will sometimes work.
Activating page 20 will never work.

With my actual watch, the numbers are lower and more variable:
Activating page 5 will always work.
Activating pages 6 - 10 will sometimes work.
Activating page 16 or more will never work.

I tried to setup the page later in method:"didAppear" and it didn't help if I want to have 10 or 20 pages.

The only work-around I found involved doing a series of jumps forwards through the pages each separated by a delay.
I found jumping forward by 3 pages with a delay of 0.3 seconds worked all the time, but it makes the interface look terrible as it takes more than a second to get to the destination page with the screen flashing up intervening pages as you go.

Is this a known bug with becomeCurrentPage()?
Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Calling becomeCurrentPage() from the main thread  worked for me.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/becomeCurrentPage) mentions calling becomeCurrentPage() always from the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{  
     controller.becomeCurrentPage()  
})
```